# Neo4j creating relationships

Tags: neo4j

I've got two csv files imported into neo4j  named : `uniq_names` and `all_names`. I've got one column  and about 5000 rows in `uniq_names` file , and i've got  three columns : `name` , `id1` and `id2` it's about 300000 rows in `all_names` file.
Now i'm trying to create relationship  with code below:

```
 MATCH (a:uniq_names),(b:all_names)
    WHERE a.name=b.name  AND b.id1<>b.id2
    CREATE (a)-[:child]->(b);
```

as i execute the code it thinks about 20 minutes but returns: " 0 rows returned " as result , and it down't create any relationship.it works perfectly when i've  got 1000 rows in all_names file and 50 rows in uniq_names file
I've got windows 7  64bit,  jdk 1.7.0_71,  neo4j 2.1.6 enterprise. Any ideas?

Comment: I formatted your code for you, make sure for further questions you do yourself using this page for reference! http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

That query basically creates a cross product of you 5k `uniq_names` and 300k `all_names`, so 1.5bn operations - is not very efficient.

To optimize:

Create an index: `CREATE INDEX ON :all_names(name)`. Then first go over all `uniq_names` and find corresponding `all_names` via an index lookup, check the id condition and create the relationships:

```
MATCH (a:uniq_names) 
WITH a
MATCH (b:all_names {name: a.name})
WHERE b.id1<>b.id2
CREATE (a)-[:child]->(b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I tried this ,  it returned result in about 3 seconds but still 0 row returned.

Comment: since you don't have a `return` nothing is returned.

Comment: Yeah , but the problem is that it's not creating any relationships either.